# list index out of range on python function

Tags: python

New to coding and Python but I really want to learn. Trying write a function to pull the median number from a sorted list. I keep getting an error that the list index is out of range. Could someone point me in the right direction trying to understand the logic so I can think in a more programmatic way.

```
   def median(n):
       sorted(n)
       ln = len(n)
       even1 = n[ln / 2]
       even2 = n[ln /2 - 1]
       odd =  n[ln + 1 / 2]
       middle = 0
       if ln % 2 != 0:
            middle = odd
       else:
            middle = (even1 + even2) / 2.0

      return middle
```

Comment: Use `sort` instead of `sorted` for the first line. `sorted` just returns a sorted copy of `n`

Comment: What happens if `ln/2` is odd?

Comment: what's the `middle=0` line for?

Comment: `odd =  n[ln + 1 / 2]` is wrong. It is basically `ln + (1/2)` = `ln + 0` = `ln`. So you're trying to access `n[ln]` which is out of range.

Comment: When you run your python script and meet this issue, you probably could see something Begin with `Traceback (most recent call last):`
It is recommended to add that information to your question so that others could better help you, especially when your project is big. For this problem, it might be possible for people to help you out just by reading the code, but what if you have hundreds of or even thousands of lines of code.

Comment: Thanks I will remember to include next time!

Answer (score 2):

```
odd = n[ln + 1 / 2]
```

is `ln + (1/2)` ... translating to `ln + 0` = `ln`. You are trying to access element `n[ln]` which is out of range.

That line should be

```
odd = n[(ln + 1) / 2]
```

Comment: Thanks forgot all about order of operations there.

Answer (score 0):

The critical error is in computing the midpoint.  You need parentheses:

```
   odd =  n[(ln + 1) / 2]
```

You still have some index problems (remember that Python lists start at 0, not 1), but that's the source of your "out of range" problem.  To fix the odd midpoint problem, you have to back up one element:

```
   odd =  n[(ln - 1) / 2]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I totally forgot about the order of operations in the variables.  Also on for the odd variable I wasn't counting from 0 so I didn't need to add 1 to the length